# Geometry of anti-de Sitter space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

For hyperbolic space we have various models due to Klein and Poincare such as a hyperboloid of one sheet or the disc model or the upper half plane.  In anti-de Sitter space there is one more negative sign in the metric:
$$       ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 - dt_1^2 - dt_2^2 $$

I'd call this $ \mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ or something.  Is there still a separation between time-like and space like geodesics now?  Possibly: 
$$       ds^2 = \frac{1}{y^2} \left( dx^2 + dy^2 - dt_1^2 - dt_2^2 \right)  $$
Is there an analogue of the upper half-planes and are the geodesics still semi-circles there?

---

By their own admission, the quality of the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space) is in question because it lacks details:

> This article includes a list of references, related reading or external links, **but its sources remain unclear because it lacks inline citations**. Please help to improve this article by introducing more precise citations. (June 2016) (Learn how and when to remove this template message)

Primary sources on anti de Sitter space would be appreciated.  They do offer a few pieces of information by way of analogy:

$$ S^2 \simeq \frac{O(3)}{O(2)} \text{ and } AdS_3 = \frac{O(2,2)}{O(1,1)} $$

Therefore, AdS is a homogenous space.  There are Poincaré coordinates, but Wikipedia warns us these do not cover all of anti de-Sitter space.  They point to the [notes](http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/Kurs.pdf) of Ingemar Bengtsson (which does have lots of pictures!  but also missing quite a few).

Comment: What precisely do you want to know that can't be found in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space ?

Comment: @S.Carnahan in Euclidean space or Hyperbolic space we can answer geometric questions in exquisite detail, but these black hole solutions have metrics that may contain undiscovered properties.  I have found this basic [tour](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/moschella.pdf) of AdS which gives some kind of orientation.

Comment: (1) AdS is **not** a black hole solution. (2) See the sections concerning "hyperquadrics" in Chapters 4 and 5 of O'Neill's _Semi-Riemannian Geometry_. (3) What do you mean by "separation between time-like and space-like geodesics"? The corresponding vectors form, by definition, disjoint sets in the sphere bundle. (4) Are you just asking about whether there exists a single coordinate chart that covers the entirety of AdS? Then the answer is no since AdS is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^d$.