# What is the connection between $\mathrm{AdS}_2$ and the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

What is the connection between $\mathrm{AdS}_2$ and the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$?

Some sources seem to imply that they are the same, i.e. having at least the same symmetry group $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, however, I was not able to find sources that state this explicitly. What is the role of the Poincaré coordinates in the correspondence?

Comment: $AdS_2$ is the Lorentzian analogue of the hyperbolic plane. There is an also interesting duality relation between the hyperbolic space and the de Sitter space $dS_n$, which could be considered closer even though de Sitter is rather an analogue of the sphere.

Comment: Can you tell me what "Lorentzian analogue" means explicitly?

Comment: @horropie Any two-dimensional riemannian manifold with constant negative curvature is locally isometric to the hyperbolic plane.  The same is true if we simultaneously replace "riemannian" by "lorentzian" and "hyperbolic plane" by $AdS_2$.

Comment: Thank you! Does anyone have literature where this specific topic is discussed?

Comment: You could look up my mathematical family: Charles Frances, Abdelghani Zeghib, Thierry Barbot. I guess all have some expository work or introductions to the topic. Sorry, not in a position to look up precise references right now.

Comment: Some suggestions : https://mathoverflow.net/q/279719/6451   , linking for example to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space and 
https://web.archive.org/web/20180308101508/http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/Kurs.pdf